# Robot Framework Run Keyword If .. ELSE fails

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and I am trying to use `Run Keyword If .. ELSE ..`.

What it should do:
Add a new keyword to perform a check if a page includes the word "closed". If it does, refresh the page. If it doesn't, click element "this" and proceed with the rest of the scenario.

```
*** Keywords ***
Check if anything is closed
    ${ClickThis}  Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="this"]
    ${Closed}  Page Should Contain Element  xpath=//*[text()='Closed']
    Run Keyword If  ${Closed} =='PASS'  Reload Page  ELSE  ${ClickThis}
```

What happens when I run it:
"Closed" does not appear in the page. "this" is clicked. Then the test fails because:
`Page should have contained element 'xpath=//*[text()='Closed']' but did not`

Please, help me in correcting it.

 Edit: changed `Page Should Contain` to `Page Should Contain Element`. Same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument after the `ELSE` should be another keyword.

---

What effectively happened is that on this line

```
${ClickThis}  Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="this"]
```

you've assigned value to `${ClickThis}` - which is nothing, `${None}`, as `Click Element` doesn't return a value.

On this line, you're again assigning `${Closed}` the return value of `Page Should Contain`

```
${Closed}  Page Should Contain  xpath=//*[text()='Closed']
```

, which is not you expect it does - that itself keyword either fails (as was in your case) if the text is not there, or silently passes; but doesn't return a value.

So, to get to what you try to accomplish, use [Run Keyword And Return status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) for the "page should contain" - it will return True/False according to the exit status of the wrapped keyword:

```
${Closed}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain  xpath=//*[text()='Closed']
```

Now `${Closed}` will have value of `${True}` if the text was in the page, `${False}` otherwise; use that in the `Run Keyword If` block, passing a **keyword** as the 2nd argument:

```
Run Keyword If    ${Closed}  Reload Page    ELSE    Click Element  xpath=//*[@id="this"]
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you for explaining it.